# Exception to be handled for HttpConnection

Tags: android

Kindly provide me the code for handling the **HttpConnection or related Exceptions & how to display that to the user.**

Specifically , I would like to know how to handle **TimeOut for HttpConnection & how to display that alert to the user.**

Kindly provide the same code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sample code to handle Exceptions ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805855/sample-code-to-handle-exceptions)

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.  If you want to add additional information to a question, you should edit it or add a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code

```
HttpPost hPost = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(envelope,HTTP.UTF_8);
hPost.setEntity(se);

HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

// Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

// Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
// in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
int timeoutSocket = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(hPost);

HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
return entity;
```